# Is there a word for the other party when you do not meet your agreements?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the other party when you do not meet your agreements?
I would say something like "duped", but I don't want to give the impression it was unfair, let alone planned. I suppose something along the lines of "let down", but snappier and less sympathetic. I would say something like 'jilt', but it's not marriage specific.

Comment: A verb then? Are you looking for a word whose meaning is specific to this, because *fail* is probably [the best option](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/let%20down). Also are you looking for something formal/literary or colloquial ("You screwed me over")?

Comment: I think *jilted* is fine.   It's *stiffed* with regards to money.

Answer (score 1):

[**Aggrieved**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/aggrieved):

> 1. wronged, offended, or injured:
>    *He felt himself aggrieved.*
> 2. *Law*. deprived of legal rights or claims.

This is not emotionally loaded (except, perhaps, for the association with grief), and doesn't express any culpability towards the other party.

An example quoted on that same page (from [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/travel/unruly-airplane-passengers-bystanders-guide/2021/05/20/103bcf2c-b336-11eb-9059-d8176b9e3798_story.html)):

> *Automatically posting your images or video to social media can add to the aggrieved party’s distress.*

---

The term '***innocent** party*' is also used as opposed to the '*defaulting party*'. Unless used in combination, this might imply guilt for the other party, though.

Comment: *Aggrieved counterparty*?

Answer (score 1):

https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/accounting/reneging/

**Reneging** refers to a situation where one party goes back on a promise or breaks an agreement or contract that they had previously accepted. Every day, individuals and businesses enter into verbal or written contracts that they are expected to abide by the terms of. However, there are situations when one **party** may decide to renege on an agreement against the wishes of the other **contractual party**.

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reneger#:~:text=reneger%20(plural%20renegers),A%20person%20who%20reneges](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reneger#:%7E:text=reneger%20(plural%20renegers),A%20person%20who%20reneges).

Noun
reneger (plural renegers)

A person who reneges.

Comment: I also considered *abrogate* but like *reneged*, *abrogated* is, well, clumsy when the OP wanted "snappy."

Comment: Guess 'snappy' is subjective. Renege is short and sweet, to me. And it doesn't carry obvious judgment. One can renege for good or poor reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for an informal verb phrase, judging from your example *along the lines of "let down"*. You could say that the other party *is not **living up to** the terms of the agreement*.

The phrase lets the other party know you're not happy with the way things are going because of things they're doing or failing to do, and its informality gives them an opportunity to address the situation by discussing the matter with you, rather than immediately "lawyering up".

P.S. If it's *you* who's not living up to the agreement, you'd need to indicate the context in which you'd want to use the word or phrase.  Are you explaining your reasons to them or to someone else? Defending your actions? Seeking a rapprochement or compromise?